# Can't import files that are in the same directory as submodule

Tags: python, python-module

I have the following file structure:

```
/main/main.py
/main/sub/__init__.py
/main/sub/subtools.py
```

In `sub/__init__.py` I import all from subtools.py (`from subtools import *`).

And in `main.py` I import sub (`import sub`)

But when I do so, I get the error `no module named 'subtools'`, but if run **init**.py separately I don't get that error.

How can I fix that?

Comment: What is your working directory?

Comment: @Geekmoss /main

Answer (score 1):

For working directory `/main`:

You need to have `from sub.subtools import *` in `/main/sub/__init__.py`, you need to specify the full *"namespace"*.

Alternatively, use relative referencing: `from .subtools import *`

Then everything will work fine.

**Explanation:**

The point is that this import is always taken with respect to the current working directory (plus all directories in the PATH), in the case of relative references, the directory in which it lies is taken.

*Alternatively, workaround, but not good practice, extend the PATH variable with the `/main/sub` directory, then `from subtools import *` would work. (In some cases, this is a necessary solution.)*

Comment: Tried `from .subtools import *` but I get the error `No module named '__main__.subtools'; '__main__' is not a package`

Comment: And where is it? In `main.py` or `sub/__init__.py`?

That types of import is for `__init__.py`, `main.py` is okay.

Comment: It's in `sub/__init__.py`. also, is it considered good practice to do `from main...` inside submodules of `main`? I want to publish my module in the future and I am afraid this type of imports would break outside my workspace

Comment: Example for my question: Does numpy do `from numpy import array` inside submodules like `random` or `linalg`?

Comment: If you are creating a module, build imports path from the module root, because the module is then included in the PATH and has no problem with it.

If you are worried about collisions with imports, then you need to pay attention to the names, if the module will have a name without a collision, then there should be no problem in exceptional cases.

Comment: And tried absolute import? `from sub.subtools import *` in `sub/__init__.py`

Comment: Tried it in `sub/__init__.py`, I get the error `No module named 'sub'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221144/discussion-between-geekmoss-and-tomergt45).